# Generate new coordinates with distance + azimuth

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, excel

I currently have the following Excel data for a list of animals:

- Lambert 93 coordinates of the observer
- Azimuth of the animal
- Distance between the observer and the animal

I would like to get the Lambert 93 coordinates of the animals.
Is there a way to do this with ArcGis 10.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Bearing Distance To Line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/bearing-distance-to-line.htm) geoprocessing tool (available in all license levels). Provided this is your data,

```
ID,X,Y,Distance,Azimuth
A1,50.11,51.12,500,45
B2,50.12,51.13,2000,180
C3,50.13,51.14,5000,270
```

You would get the following data:

[image]

You can create the XY layer of the input points for visualization purposes. Then run the GP tool - you get the lines. Now you have to get the end vertex of the line created. This can be done either with arcpy, manually, or by using another GP tool called [Feature Vertices To Points](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) (Advanced license is required).

If you have more attributes stored within the table, use the ID field to move them over to the output end points layer.